# Generating histograms from "chunked" large data streams

Tags: c#

I've been working in some tools lately that analize long streams of data and extract frequent patterns, histograms, etc. for personal use. Lately I've been coding a histogram generator; that is, given a long chunked data stream, generate a histogram with all distinct chunks; typical case, given a text, generate a word histogram.

The algorithm and code I've come up with is the following:

```
public static class HistogramGenerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<HistogramItem<T>> GetHistogram<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> stream)
        => BuildHistogram(BuildTree(stream));

    private static Tree<T> BuildTree<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> stream)
    {
        var tree = new Tree<T>();

        foreach (var chunk in stream)
        {
            var currentTree = tree;

            foreach (var item in chunk)
            {
                currentTree = currentTree.Add(item);
            }

            currentTree.Count++;
        }

        return tree;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<HistogramItem<T>> BuildHistogram<T>(Tree<T> tree) => 
        getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths(tree).Select(histogram =>  new HistogramItem<T>(histogram.Count, histogram.Path.Reverse()))
                                        .OrderByDescending(h => h.Count);

    private static IEnumerable<HistogramItem<T>> getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths<T>(Tree<T> tree)
    {
        foreach (var branch in tree.Branches)
        {
            if (branch.Value.Count > 0)
            {
                //Make sure we return a valid path included in a longer one. For example: "the" inside "therefore"
                yield return new HistogramItem<T>(branch.Value.Count, new[] { branch.Key });
            }

            foreach (var subBranch in getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths(branch.Value))
            {
                yield return new HistogramItem<T>(subBranch.Count, subBranch.Path.Concat(new[] { branch.Key }));
            }
        }
    }

    //TODO: Check if this is should be kept as a struct.
    public struct HistogramItem<T>
    {
        public int Count { get; }
        public IEnumerable<T> Path { get; }

        public HistogramItem(int count, IEnumerable<T> path)
        {
            Path = path;
            Count = count;
        }
    }

    private class Tree<T>
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<T, Tree<T>> Branches { get; }

        public Tree()
        {
            Branches = new Dictionary<T, Tree<T>>();
            Count = 0;
        }

        public Tree<T> Add(T value)
        {
            Tree<T> branch;

            if (!Branches.TryGetValue(value, out branch))
            {
                branch = new Tree<T>();
                Branches.Add(value, branch);
            }

            return branch;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm reasonably happy with how it performs (aprox. 60 ms to analyze a 1.4+ million character long stream with 260k+ chunks).

Still, as a learning process, and because I know my limitations writing software (I'm relatively new though I'm trying hard to learn fast) I'd appreciate any feedback that could help optimize my code, make it more elegant and readable or pointers to alternative "simple" (if any) algorithm that would perform better.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentTree = tree;
foreach (var item in chunk)
{
     currentTree = currentTree.Add(item);
}
currentTree.Count++;
```

That function shouldn't need to know how to traverse a tree. That functionality belongs to `Tree`, not to the invoking site.

A simple `tree.Add(chunk);` is much cleaner in this context. The complexity of building and traversing the tree should be hidden entirely hidden inside the `Tree` class:

```
public void Add(IEnumerable<T> path)
{
    var node = this;
    foreach (var item in path)
    {
        node = node.GetChild(item);
    }
    node.Count++;
}
```

There is no longer a need to expose the original `Tree::Add` publicly, as the only legit caller is now inside the same class:

```
private Tree<T> GetChild(T value)
{
    Tree<T> node;

    if (!Branches.TryGetValue(value, out node))
    {
        node = new Tree<T>();
        Branches.Add(value, node);
    }
    return node;
}
```

---

The second occurrence where the functionality should have been encapsulated inside `Tree` is `getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths`. This function requires specific knowledge about how the storage is implemented, so it's inseparable from it.

This also raises concerns regarding the visbility of `Tree::Count` and `Tree::Branches`. These properties don't need to be exposed, if the methods belonging to `Tree` are actually moved into that class.

For the invoking side, only the capabilities of storing, counting, and reciting stored paths are of interest. Nothing else, especially not how the tree is implemented. Not even the fact that it is implemented as a tree at all.

---

```
foreach (var subBranch in getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths(branch.Value))
{
    yield return new HistogramItem<T>(
      subBranch.Count,
      subBranch.Path.Concat(new[] { branch.Key })
    );
}
```

This doesn't look right. You are essentially recreating and discarding `HistogramItem` instances over and over again, while you are technically only appending to the `Path` property.

`HistogramItem::Path` should either be mutable, or simply add the current path suffix as a parameter to `getAllCurrentTreeReversedPaths`, so you can create `HistogramItem` instances with the correct properties right away.

Comment: Thanks for the input. While I do agree with your third comment, the fact that `HistogramItem` is a struct and most of them are very short lived I don't really see an issue and I like immutability whenever I can use it cheap. About your first comment I don't altogether agree because `Add(chunk)` is simply not enough, you always need to traverse the tree somehow to add in the right place. I don't see how you actually propose to get around that encapsulating everything inside`Tree`.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, yes I could move the method inside`Tree` , but I'd still have to let `Branches` visible for the reasons stated above, and I can make  `Count` readonly with a private setter so I don't see much issue with it being visible either.

Comment: @InBetween I think there is a little misunderstanding regarding the difference between `private` and "accessing only instance properties". When you encapsulate the logic for traversing a tree inside `Tree`, that doesn't limit you from iterating over the leaf nodes and their properties from within `Tree::Add`. `private`doesn't state that the variable is **local**, but only that access is limited to methods from the same class.

Comment: The private issue is regarding `Count`. About the other issue regarding encapsulating `Add` is that I always need to know the parent node I'm inserting at, therefore when calling `Add` form the outside I somehow need to know where to insert therefore I need to traverse the tree externally. Otherwise, when building the tree, how would I add `e`of `the` with a simple `Add(e)`?

Comment: @InBetween By literally using `this` as the starting point. I will edit the code sample into the post.

Comment: @InBetween Regarding immutability, that's not the issue with `HistogramItem`, respectively it wouldn't be if you would aim for getting it straight on the first attempt. But if you know that you are going to mutate the containers content immediately, it's misplaced. (And the optimal solution in this case is to avoid the mutation all together, by computing the suffix once per branch, and not over and over again for each single leaf. Make good use of the pre-order traversion you have chosen.)